# Update to Rails 3.2 get my a couple of strange behaviors in my test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

I have upgraded to Rails 3.2, and I am now getting a ton of extra log messages in my test suite, related to the logging of request such as 'GET api/v1/properties/11967/tenants'.  Anybody know why I'm getting all of these logging messages, more importantly how I turn them off?

Joe

```
GET api/v1/properties/11986/maintenance_issues
GET api/v1/properties/11990/maintenance_issues
GET api/v1/properties/11994/maintenance_issues/1678
GET api/v1/properties/11998/maintenance_issues/1679
GET api/v1/properties/12002/maintenance_issues/1680
GET api/v1/properties/12006/maintenance_issues/1681
GET api/v1/properties/12010/maintenance_issues/1682
GET api/v1/properties/12014/maintenance_issues/1
```

This is the output when I run rspec spec.

Comment: Could you post an example? Indent with four spaces for proper formatting.